# Is it possible to play audio/mpeg stream in a Firefox extention?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm trying to play an audio/mpeg stream in Firefox. It works in Chrome with `<audio>` tag but not in Firefox. Is it possible to play audio/mpeg in Firefox? Maybe with a flash player or something like that.

Comment: `m3u` is simply a list of titles - what's the problem with parsing it and passing the URLs to flowplayer?

Comment: @WladimirPalant, it was a pain to parse a m3u on a client side. Anyway, it's a bit embarrassing but the question was actually misleading. It's not m3u, it returns `audio/mpeg` content-type. I changed the question.

Comment: The answer to your new question is: "no, Firefox has an Ogg Vorbis decoder but not an MP3 one".

Comment: @WladimirPalant, oh, too bad. But it's possible to play it somehow with a flash player, right?

Comment: Well, Flash Player has a decoder for MP3... But do you seriously want to reply on Flash in an extension?

Comment: I don't, but it seems it's the only option now. I cannot recode the stream to ogg. And I've installed several internet radio plugins for Firefox - they don't work at all. I managed to find only one extention that can play audio stream. It works on PC and Macs and it uses flash.